# How to get decimal by long divide operation

Tags: c#

```
long a = 50000;
long b = 98600000;
```

I have tried with

```
float c = a/b;
decimal c =a/b;
double c = a/b;
```

But all of them always get 0

How do I get the result (0.00507...)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're diving a `long` by a `long`, which always yields a `long`. You need to cast one of the values:

```
float c = ((float)a)/b;
decimal c =((decimal)a)/b;
double c = ((double)a)/b;
```

Comment: I find this answer to be better than relying on a multiply operation to change the type.  Yes, that works perfectly fine, but casting to decimal (or whatever) is more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

When dividing two `long` types you will always get a `long` as a result regardless of whether the receiving type is of `decimal`, `double` or `float`.

to receive a `decimal` result:

```
decimal c = (decimal)a / b;
```

to receive a `float` result:

```
float c = (float)a / b;
```

to receive a `double` result:

```
double c = a * 1.0 / b;
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you pick the denominator?

Comment: didn't really think much about it to be honest as it didnt matter, but will change to the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

You get 0 since the division takes place in *integer arithmetic*, irrespective of the type of the variable to which the expression is assigned.

To remedy, you can use

```
1.0 * a / b
```

for the `double` case,

```
1.0f * a / b
```

for the `float` case, and

```
1.0M * a / b
```

for the decimal case. There are other ways, but I find this approach clearest. The fact that you see a literal at the start of the terms signals to the reader of your code from the get-go that you know what you're doing.

The `M` denotes a `decimal` literal in C#. (And `1.0f` denotes a `float` literal.) This technique forces the conversion of the `a` and `b` to the appropriate type for the division.

Finally, I'd avoid any expression that involves the implicit conversion of a `long` to a `float`.

Comment: `1.0f * a` is too *cruel* for `double` case: it can result in precision loss (we insist on `float` which is 32-bit when having `long` - 64 bit long, e.g. `a = 123456789123456L`). `1.0d` or just `1.0` in case of double is the better choice. P.S. I'm not the second downvoter.

Comment: I have downvoted because while this answer generally works, I find casting at least one of the operands to be the much more simple and obvious solution, as demonstrated in Sean's answer.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Agree; I find it yukky that C# fails to compiler 1.0 * a / b assigned to a float. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Indeed downvotes are an expression of choice. I really dislike the other way myself as I find it to be unclear. But in C# you might have a point, given that `1.0 * a / b` can't be assigned to a `float`.

Comment: More on this, with this answer, I have to understand more (and more understanding isn't necessarily a bad thing, but...). It introduces another operand, and I have to consider order of operation and still understand how using operands of different types effect the output type. I might as well cut out the extra complexity (extra operand, order of operation) and go straight to the conversion myself. It's the lowest common denominator of what I need to know in either case.

Comment: I'm a old C and C++ cat where my way is idiomatic, and there are fewer things more important than learning your type conversions.

Comment: I can appreciate your perspective, and certainly old habits (patterns and idioms learned earlier) die hard.

Comment: I also wonder if `((double)a)/b;` is vulnerable to refactoring to `(double)(a/b);`.